# HTML, CSS: Hover not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website but for some reason my `a:hover` is not working. When I hover nothing happens. I need some help.

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LfaLt1db/

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: The fiddle that you have provided is very complex. Which part of the website do you want to react on hovering?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the SHORTEST code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Mithrandir Not necessarily, an `a` tag within that has inline styling of `text-decoration:none;` which is being seen as more important in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have `.main-content a` structure in yor HTML, and `.main-content li a` in your CSS. Just remove `li

```css
.main-content a:hover, .sub-content a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #008080;
}
```

Or add

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

to your CSS file.

Comment: Unless they're wanting it to apply to the menu links.  In that case, the `.main-content` part is what's wrong.  It's hard to tell which is the desired outcome.

Comment: Adding onto this, some of OP's `a` tags have inline styles of `text-decoration:none;` which is is looked at as more 'important' by the browser, so in your CSS it isn't overwriting.

Comment: @Albzi perhaps rephrase that "your" refers to the OP rather than Edward!

Comment: Thanks @Martin, done :)

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
  .main-content li a:hover, .sub-content li a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        background-color: #008080;
    }
```

css code to

```
.main-navbar li:hover, .sub-navbar li:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        background-color: #008080;
    }
```